# Manipular botón actualizar JavaScript

Tags: javascript, formularios, url

Es posible manipular el botón actualizar? O desactivarlo? Es que tengo que sobrescribir un Url con

```
  window.history.replaceState({}, '', 'NuevaUrl');
```

Pero cuando se da actualizar truena, ya lo solucioné cuando se actualiza la página con `F5` pero si aprietas el botón del navegador actualizar ya no lo hace.

Este es mi código en el cual cambio el `URL` y manipulo el `F5`

```
var URLactual = '';

$(document).ready(function () {


if (URLactual == '') {

    URLactual = window.parent.location.href;
}

window.history.replaceState({}, '', 'NuevaUrl');


$(document.body).on("keydown", this, function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 116) {
        window.location.assign(URLactual);

    }
});

history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.go(1);
};
```

});

Comment: Para que veamos exactamente que es lo que estas buscando, podrías mostrar como has cambiado el de la tecla F5?

Comment: oh si claro ya lo añado a mi pregunta.